# Questions with Edit or PS Sections

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, moderation

Many questions may need to be edited or some additional notes added after they are asked. One can edit the whole question in such cases and so some others may check it via history or can add `Edit` or `PS` sections.

Problem is that: answers may be invalid due to changes.

For the first approach:

I personally think that people do not check question histories for if any major changes have been done when they become suspicious about an answer being valid or not.

For the second approach:

People can realise that something has been realised/or inputs are improved after the question was asked and keep that in mind when they check answers. However you cannot understand the real question at a glance when you read some of them.

Which one is the right approach as a user or reviewer (both can be right too)?

Comment: I have no idea, what you mean with Edit/PS sections. Could you give an (visual) example?

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt: "EDIT 2: To address problems @ soandso raised: Code originally used a frobber that I omitted; I've written a condensed version: <code block>."

Comment: @NathanTuggy ah text sections made by a user. Thanks, I thought to complicated.

Comment: Cross-site duplicates: *[Is it recommended to notify the answer “Edits” with an heading followed by the edit content?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230692)* and *[When is “EDIT”/“UPDATE” appropriate in a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127639)*

Comment: On-site duplicate (but now deleted - only visible to 10K+ers): *[Should EDIT: or other similar monikers be allowed in questions or answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266164)*

Answer (score 30):

> Problem is that: answers may be invalid due to changes.

Edits that change what the original question is about and invalidate existing answers should be rolled back. If the user asked the wrong thing or has a new question, they need to make a new post.

If the edit simply clarified the existing question and someone answered before it was clear, or they misunderstood the original question, that's on the user that answered. (This can get hairy since users can disagree on whether the original question was clear or not.)

Whether an answer is right or wrong should not change due to an edit.

> Which one is the right approach as a user or reviewer (both can be
>   right too)?

My understanding is that putting a header in a post like **Edit** or **P.S.** is redundant since the edit history exists, which makes it noise that should be edited out.

I also think it's bad because it encourages users to tack on all new content to the end of a post instead of improving the existing text and code sections. This can make questions very long and hard to follow, as you've already pointed out.

But most importantly, the problem you're talking about shouldn't happen and should be corrected when it does.

Comment: The edit history is no good argument, as it is very hidden. Do you look at the edit history when reading a question? So an "Edit: added my test data to the example code" may actually help you to understand why some answers are telling there is no test data, even when there is some.

Comment: @allo - The "Edited" link is always in the same place, centered just below the question. But there shouldn't be answers saying there's no test data. That's a comment at best and comments can be deleted once they become obsolete.

Comment: @allo But even without knowing where the link is, most users know that posts *can* be edited. So if you see something saying "test data is missing" and it's not missing you can assume that the post was edited to add it.

Comment: Of course. But "can assume" is no good UX.